# Looking for an older sci fi novel where a woman's skin/body is colonised by colourful bacteria or algae

Tags: story-identification

I read this novel when I was younger, so it may be anywhere from 80s - 00s.

The part of the story that stayed with me was where a woman was knocked unconscious by a scientist who had been experimenting with algae or bacteria. He infects her skin with cultures of the colourful algae or bacteria while she's unconscious, and it begins to grow all over her, changing her skin into colonies of these organisms or plants. She slips in and out of consciousness for a while as he does it. It was a bit body horror.

The bits I'm less sure of: I believe they were looking for a solution to a problem in the atmosphere (maybe running out of air or drinkable water?) or their colony was being destroyed/eaten by the bacteria or substance, or they were dying out for some reason. The work that the man does on the woman's skin is critical to solving the problem.

The woman was described as having darker skin. I remember it being a planet where it was not possible to stay outside, possibly a water planet. The man may have been her mentor or father, unsure.